# How can I save all items in listbox to MYSQL database using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listboxitem

This is my code and I can save only the first item. I need to save the entire list in one database column. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Dim mysql As String = "UPDATE tbl_item SET my_item = (@myitems) WHERE id = '" & Label6.Text & "'"


Dim mycmd As New MySqlCommand(mysql, sConnection)

Dim values As New List(Of String)

values.Add(ListBox1.Items.Add(values))

Dim sqlParam As New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@myitems", .DbType = DbType.String}

mycmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To values.Count - 1
    sqlParam.Value = (ListBox1.Items(i) & ";")
    mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Comment: "I need to save all list in one database column" - hint: why might that be a bad idea?

Comment: is it a bad idea to save all list in one column? coz I need all that items together when I need to display it in my report.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To values.Count - 1
         If sqlparam.value = "" Then
            sqlparam.value = listbox1.Items(i) & ";"
        Else
            sqlparam.value = sqlparam.value & listbox.Items(i) & ";"
        End If

    Next       
   mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If this code failed, then try to put mycmd.execute.... inside..

Comment: Thanks for your help Never_Mind .. I put mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery() outside the for statement but no success.. Only the first item in listbox is being save.

Comment: When I executed the code you posted, only the second item in the list was save in the database.. even when I inserted mycmd.executeNonquery() in the for statement.. the result is the same..

Comment: So, how about you try another way? First, get all the listbox item to the Textbox, then you just execute from the textbox to Sql. Of course, you must set the textbox visible to false. Can?

Comment: yeah, thanks for your time, Im just trying now different ways to meet my need.. i think i should create another table in my database and separate each item from my listbox per column and use a foreign key..

Comment: @bok actually you dont need like that, cause it will only take your time and process will slow, better use what i told. First add to your textbox, then from your textbox execute to your SQL, isn't it more fast better then execute two time to your sql?